# Exclude a string starting with certain letter by a SQL query in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, substring

I'm trying to exclude values from a larger public table in Googles BigQuery using the following SQL lines.
The last line has the purpose to exclude entries, that start with a certain letter, e.g. 'C'.
For some reason, when I add the line, the count increases. Logically the selected rows should decrease and I can’t figure out why.

How can I make the exclusion work?

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications`,
unnest(description_localized) as description_unnest,
unnest(claims_localized) as claims_unnest,
unnest(cpc) as cpc_unnest
where description_unnest.language in ('en','EN')
and claims_unnest.language in ('en','EN')
and publication_date >19900101
and (SUBSTRING(cpc_unnest.code,1,1) <> 'C');
```

Comment: Without last condition, it returns 207,516,155 rows, and 185,128,825 rows with the condition.

Comment: As mentioned by the comment above, your exclusion seems to work. What is the issue that you encounter?

Comment: OK. I think I found the mistakes I made
1) I compared the number of cases with and without this line #7. That was leading to the increased rows.
#7 unnest(cpc) as cpc_unnest

2) THIS IS MOST IMPORTANT: I did not want to know the number of rows, but the number of unique entries. As the table is build up according to the publication numbers, I can use this number to search for unique entries. The SQL command Count(DISTICT attribut) can be used:
SELECT Count(DISTINCT publication_number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I think I found the mistakes I made

1. I compared the number of cases with and without this line #7. That was leading to the increased rows.

#7 unnest(cpc) as cpc_unnest

2. THIS IS MOST IMPORTANT: I did not want to know the number of rows, but the number of unique entries. As the table is build up according to the publication numbers, I can use this number to search for unique entries. The SQL command Count(DISTINCT attribut) can be used:

SELECT Count(DISTINCT publication_number)

The whole solution is this

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT publication_number)
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications`,
unnest(description_localized) as description_unnest,
unnest(claims_localized) as claims_unnest,
unnest(cpc) as cpc_unnest
where description_unnest.language in ('en','EN')
and claims_unnest.language in ('en','EN')
and publication_date >19900101
and (SUBSTRING(cpc_unnest.code,1,1) <> 'C')
```